# Add SortFilterProxyModel to my QTreeView crashes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

When i insert the QSortFilterProxyModel to my QTreeview. It appears to crash and my buttons for adding, editing no longer appear to work reliably. Where did I go wrong here? My goal here is to add the Sort model so i can add a search bar which is simple to do.

[image]

Here is the working version...

```
import sys
import os
import random
from enum import IntEnum
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, job, thumbnail=''):
        self.name = name
        self.job = job
        self.thumbnail = thumbnail


class Family:
    def __init__(self, name, people, thumbnail=''):
        self.name = name
        self.people = people
        self.thumbnail = thumbnail
        self.isExpanded = False


class FamilyModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):

    class Roles(IntEnum):
        ItemRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 10

    def __init__(self, items, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.items = items
        self.columnNames = ['Last Name/First Name', 'Job']

    # subclass methods
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.columnNames[section]
        return None

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.columnNames)

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if parent.column() > 0:
            return 0

        if not parent.isValid():
            return len(self.items)
        
        item = parent.internalPointer()
        if isinstance(item, Family):
            return len(item.people)
        
        return 0

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if not self.hasIndex(row, column, parent):
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        if not parent.isValid():
            return self.createIndex(row, column, self.items[row])

        parent_item = parent.internalPointer()
        return self.createIndex(row, column, parent_item.people[row])

    def parent(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        item = index.internalPointer()
        if isinstance(item, Person):
            family = next((x for x in self.items if item in x.people), None)
            if family:
                return self.createIndex(self.items.index(family), 0, family)
        return QtCore.QModelIndex()  

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        item = index.internalPointer()

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if isinstance(item, Family):
                if index.column() == 0:
                    return item.name
            elif isinstance(item, Person):
                if index.column() == 0:
                    return item.name
                elif index.column() == 1:
                    return item.job
            else:
                return None
        elif role == self.Roles.ItemRole:
            return item

        return None

    def removeRows(self, row, count, index):
        self.beginRemoveRows(index, row, row+count-1)
        for i in reversed(range(row, row+count)):
            if not index.isValid():
                self.items.pop(i)
            else:
                self.items[index.row()].people.pop(i)
        self.endRemoveRows()
        return True

    # extended methods
    def itemFromIndex(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            return index.internalPointer()
        return None

    def clear_items(self):
        '''
        Removes all items
        '''
        self.beginResetModel()
        self.items.clear()
        self.endResetModel()

    def set_families(self, families):
        '''
        Directly set the items
        '''
        self.beginResetModel()
        self.items = families
        self.endResetModel()

    def append_families(self, items):
        '''
        Add new families
        '''
        first = self.rowCount()
        last = first + len(items)
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), first, last)
        self.items.extend(items)
        self.endInsertRows()


class FamilyViewer(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, families):
        super().__init__()

        self.treeview = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self)
        self.treeview.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.treeview.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        
        self.itemModel = FamilyModel(families)
        self.treeview.setModel(self.itemModel)
        self.treeview.expandAll()
        self.treeview.header().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.treeview.collapsed.connect(self.on_collapsed_state)
        self.treeview.expanded.connect(self.on_expanded_state)

        self.set_families_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Set Families")
        self.set_families_button.clicked.connect(self.set_families)

        self.add_family_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add Family")
        self.add_family_button.clicked.connect(self.add_family)

        self.clear_all_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Clear All")
        self.clear_all_button.clicked.connect(self.clear_all)

        self.print_selected_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Print Selected")
        self.print_selected_button.clicked.connect(self.print_selected)

        self.remove_selected_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Remove Selected")
        self.remove_selected_button.clicked.connect(self.remove_selected)


        self.add_person_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add Person")
        self.add_person_button.clicked.connect(self.add_person)

        self.update_selected_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Change/Update Selected")
        self.update_selected_button.clicked.connect(self.update_selected)

        button_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        button_layout.addWidget(self.set_families_button)
        button_layout.addWidget(self.add_family_button)
        button_layout.addWidget(self.add_person_button)
        button_layout.addWidget(self.remove_selected_button)
        button_layout.addWidget(self.clear_all_button)
        button_layout.addWidget(self.update_selected_button)
        button_layout.addWidget(self.print_selected_button)

        main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.treeview)
        main_layout.addLayout(button_layout)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)


    def random_person(self):
        first_names = ['Zephyr', 'Seraphina', 'Thaddeus', 'Evadne', 'Oberon', 'Isolde', 'Leif', 'Eulalia', 'Caius', 'Xanthe']
        jobs = ['Ethnobotanist', 'Cryptographer', 'Geotechnical Engineer', 'Aquaculturist', 'Medical Illustrator', 'Flavor Chemist', 'Music Therapist', 'Renewable Energy Analyst', 'Cybersecurity Consultant', 'Wilderness Guide']
        return Person(random.choice(first_names), random.choice(jobs))


    def random_family(self):
        last_names = ['Abernathy', 'Calhoun', 'Dempsey', 'Ellington', 'Farraday', 'Granger', 'Haverford', 'Inglewood', 'Jamison', 'Kensington']
        new_family = Family(random.choice(last_names), [])
        new_family.isExpanded = random.choice([True, False])
        for i in range(random.randint(1, 5)):
            new_family.people.append(self.random_person())
        return new_family


    def set_families(self):
        families = []
        for i in range(random.randint(1, 5)):
            families.append(self.random_family())
        self.itemModel.set_families(families)

        for i in range(self.itemModel.rowCount()):
            item = self.itemModel.itemFromIndex(self.itemModel.index(i, 0))
            if item and item.isExpanded:
                self.treeview.expand(self.itemModel.index(i, 0))


    def add_family(self):
        self.itemModel.append_families([self.random_family()])


    def clear_all(self):
        self.itemModel.clear_items()


    def print_selected(self):
        selected = self.treeview.selectionModel().selectedRows()
        for mindex in selected:
            item = mindex.data(FamilyModel.Roles.ItemRole)
            print(vars(item))


    def remove_selected(self):
        selectionModel = self.treeview.selectionModel()
        while len(selectionModel.selectedIndexes()):
            mindex = selectionModel.selectedIndexes()[0]
            self.itemModel.removeRow(mindex.row(), mindex.parent())


    def on_collapsed_state(self, modelIndex):
        item = modelIndex.data(FamilyModel.Roles.ItemRole)
        item.isExpanded = False


    def on_expanded_state(self, modelIndex):
        item = modelIndex.data(FamilyModel.Roles.ItemRole)
        item.isExpanded = True


    def add_person(self):
        selected = self.treeview.selectionModel().selectedRows()
        for mindex in selected:
            item = mindex.data(FamilyModel.Roles.ItemRole)
            if isinstance(item, Family):
                item.people.append(self.random_person())
        self.itemModel.layoutChanged.emit()


    def update_selected(self):
        selected = self.treeview.selectionModel().selectedRows()
        for mindex in selected:
            item = mindex.data(FamilyModel.Roles.ItemRole)
            item.name = random.choice(['A','B','C','D'])
        self.itemModel.layoutChanged.emit()


def main():

    # Create sample data
    familyA = Family(
        'Roberston',
        [
            Person('Kevin', 'Nurse'),
            Person('Ashley', 'Lifeguard'),
            Person('Michael', 'Unemployed'),
        ]
    )
    familyB = Family(
        'Grainger',
        [
            Person('Emily', 'Clerk'),
            Person('Emma', 'Security'),
            Person('Ron', 'Teacher'),
            Person('Jerry', 'Wizard'),
        ]
    )

    families = [familyA, familyB]

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    viewer = FamilyViewer(families)
    viewer.setWindowTitle('Family Viewer')
    viewer.resize(500, 600)
    viewer.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the broken one...

```
import sys
import os
import random
from enum import IntEnum
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, job, thumbnail=''):
        self.name = name
        self.job = job
        self.thumbnail = thumbnail


class Family:
    def __init__(self, name, people, thumbnail=''):
        self.name = name
        self.people = people
        self.thumbnail = thumbnail
        self.isExpanded = False


class FamilyModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):

    class Roles(IntEnum):
        ItemRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 10

    def __init__(self, items, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.items = items
        self.columnNames = ['Last Name/First Name', 'Job']

    # subclass methods
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.columnNames[section]
        return None

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.columnNames)

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if parent.column() > 0:
            return 0

        if not parent.isValid():
            return len(self.items)
        
        item = parent.internalPointer()
        if isinstance(item, Family):
            return len(item.people)
        
        return 0

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if not self.hasIndex(row, column, parent):
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        if not parent.isValid():
            return self.createIndex(row, column, self.items[row])

        parent_item = parent.internalPointer()
        return self.createIndex(row, column, parent_item.people[row])

    def parent(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        item = index.internalPointer()
        if isinstance(item, Person):
            family = next((x for x in self.items if item in x.people), None)
            if family:
                return self.createIndex(self.items.index(family), 0, family)
        return QtCore.QModelIndex()  

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        item = index.internalPointer()

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if isinstance(item, Family):
                if index.column() == 0:
                    return item.name
            elif isinstance(item, Person):
                if index.column() == 0:
                    return item.name
                elif index.column() == 1:
                    return item.job
            else:
                return None
        elif role == self.Roles.ItemRole:
            return item

        return None

    def removeRows(self, row, count, index):
        self.beginRemoveRows(index, row, row+count-1)
        for i in reversed(range(row, row+count)):
            if not index.isValid():
                self.items.pop(i)
            else:
                self.items[index.row()].people.pop(i)
        self.endRemoveRows()
        return True

    # extended methods
    def itemFromIndex(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            return index.internalPointer()
        return None

    def clear_items(self):
        '''
        Removes all items
        '''
        self.beginResetModel()
        self.items.clear()
        self.endResetModel()

    def set_families(self, families):
        '''
        Directly set the items
        '''
        self.beginResetModel()
        self.items = families
        self.endResetModel()

    def append_families(self, items):
        '''
        Add new families
        '''
        first = self.rowCount()
        last = first + len(items)
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), first, last)
        self.items.extend(items)
        self.endInsertRows()


class FamilyViewer(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, families):
        super().__init__()

        self.itemModel = FamilyModel(families)

        self.proxyModel = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(self.itemModel)
        self.proxyModel.setSortCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.proxyModel.setFilterCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.proxyModel.setDynamicSortFilter(True)
        self.proxyModel.setFilterKeyColumn(0)
        self.proxyModel.sort(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)

        self.treeview = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self)
        self.treeview.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.treeview.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.treeview.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.treeview.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.treeview.setModel(self.proxyModel)
        self.treeview.expandAll()
        self.treeview.header().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.treeview.collapsed.connect(self.on_collapsed_state)
        self.treeview.expanded.connect(self.on_expanded_state)

        self.set_families_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Set Families")
        self.set_families_button.clicked.connect(self.set_families)

        self.add_family_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add Family")
        self.add_family_button.clicked.connect(self.add_family)

        self.clear_all_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Clear All")
        self.clear_all_button.clicked.connect(self.clear_all)

        self.print_selected_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Print Selected")
        self.print_selected_button.clicked.connect(self.print_selected)

        self.remove_selected_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Remove Selected")
        self.remove_selected_button.clicked.connect(self.remove_selected)


        self.add_person_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add Person")
        self.add_person_button.clicked.connect(self.add_person)

        self.update_selected_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Change/Update Selected")
        self.update_selected_button.clicked.connect(self.update_selected)

        button_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        button_layout.addWidget(self.set_families_button)
        button_layout.addWidget(self.add_family_button)
        button_layout.addWidget(self.add_person_button)
        button_layout.addWidget(self.remove_selected_button)
        button_layout.addWidget(self.clear_all_button)
        button_layout.addWidget(self.update_selected_button)
        button_layout.addWidget(self.print_selected_button)

        main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.treeview)
        main_layout.addLayout(button_layout)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)


    def random_person(self):
        first_names = ['Zephyr', 'Seraphina', 'Thaddeus', 'Evadne', 'Oberon', 'Isolde', 'Leif', 'Eulalia', 'Caius', 'Xanthe']
        jobs = ['Ethnobotanist', 'Cryptographer', 'Geotechnical Engineer', 'Aquaculturist', 'Medical Illustrator', 'Flavor Chemist', 'Music Therapist', 'Renewable Energy Analyst', 'Cybersecurity Consultant', 'Wilderness Guide']
        return Person(random.choice(first_names), random.choice(jobs))


    def random_family(self):
        last_names = ['Abernathy', 'Calhoun', 'Dempsey', 'Ellington', 'Farraday', 'Granger', 'Haverford', 'Inglewood', 'Jamison', 'Kensington']
        new_family = Family(random.choice(last_names), [])
        new_family.isExpanded = random.choice([True, False])
        for i in range(random.randint(1, 5)):
            new_family.people.append(self.random_person())
        return new_family


    def set_families(self):
        families = []
        for i in range(random.randint(1, 5)):
            families.append(self.random_family())
        self.itemModel.set_families(families)

        for i in range(self.itemModel.rowCount()):
            item = self.itemModel.itemFromIndex(self.itemModel.index(i, 0))
            if item and item.isExpanded:
                self.treeview.expand(self.itemModel.index(i, 0))


    def add_family(self):
        self.itemModel.append_families([self.random_family()])


    def clear_all(self):
        self.itemModel.clear_items()


    def print_selected(self):
        selected = self.treeview.selectionModel().selectedRows()
        for mindex in selected:
            item = mindex.data(FamilyModel.Roles.ItemRole)
            print(vars(item))


    def remove_selected(self):
        selectionModel = self.treeview.selectionModel()
        while len(selectionModel.selectedIndexes()):
            mindex = selectionModel.selectedIndexes()[0]
            self.itemModel.removeRow(mindex.row(), mindex.parent())


    def on_collapsed_state(self, modelIndex):
        item = modelIndex.data(FamilyModel.Roles.ItemRole)
        item.isExpanded = False


    def on_expanded_state(self, modelIndex):
        item = modelIndex.data(FamilyModel.Roles.ItemRole)
        item.isExpanded = True


    def add_person(self):
        selected = self.treeview.selectionModel().selectedRows()
        for mindex in selected:
            item = mindex.data(FamilyModel.Roles.ItemRole)
            if isinstance(item, Family):
                item.people.append(self.random_person())
        self.itemModel.layoutChanged.emit()


    def update_selected(self):
        selected = self.treeview.selectionModel().selectedRows()
        for mindex in selected:
            item = mindex.data(FamilyModel.Roles.ItemRole)
            item.name = random.choice(['A','B','C','D'])
        self.itemModel.layoutChanged.emit()


def main():

    # Create sample data
    familyA = Family(
        'Roberston',
        [
            Person('Kevin', 'Nurse'),
            Person('Ashley', 'Lifeguard'),
            Person('Michael', 'Unemployed'),
        ]
    )
    familyB = Family(
        'Grainger',
        [
            Person('Emily', 'Clerk'),
            Person('Emma', 'Security'),
            Person('Ron', 'Teacher'),
            Person('Jerry', 'Wizard'),
        ]
    )

    families = [familyA, familyB]

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    viewer = FamilyViewer(families)
    viewer.setWindowTitle('Family Viewer')
    viewer.resize(500, 600)
    viewer.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Wrong usage of `layoutChanged`

One of the common mistakes when implementing or interacting with Qt item models is to use the `layoutChanged` signal for the wrong purposes.

That signal "works" for simple cases, mostly because item views generally accept it as some sort of "reset" that rarely has issues when the view has direct access to a "final" model, and discarded indexes (including changed *persistent* indexes) don't normally cause issues.

Still, in principle, that signal should only be used for its specific purpose:

> This signal is emitted whenever the layout of items exposed by the model has changed; for example, when the model has been sorted.

I admit that the explanation is a bit vague, so I'll make it more clear: the *layout change* mostly involves the way *existing indexes* are *laid out*.

So, emitting it for the following (among others) is not correct:

- when data of existing items has changed;
- when indexes are being added or removed;

Most importantly, the documentation points out a fundamental requirement:

> When subclassing QAbstractItemModel or QAbstractProxyModel, ensure that you emit `layoutAboutToBeChanged()` before changing the order of items or altering the structure of the data you expose to views, and emit `layoutChanged()` after changing the layout.

Views can "overlook" the missing `layoutAboutToBeChanged()` signal (it's normally used only by headers), but that step is of extreme importance when dealing with proxy models, because that signal is the only way those objects have to keep track of existing (persistent) indexes before the change, and they use it so to properly map those indexes again when the layout change is completed and eventually sort/filter items in case they need it.

### Simple (but still not appropriate) fix

A basic workaround is to properly call `layoutAboutToBeChanged()` *before* making any change. For instance, in `add_person()`:

```py
    def add_person(self):
        self.itemModel.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit() # <- this!
        ...
        self.itemModel.layoutChanged.emit()
```

Note that when I wrote that "is not correct" above I didn't mean that it's completely wrong, but it is still not appropriate, and that's because it signals the connected views (or proxies) that the *whole* layout has changed, even when it's not.

In an item view, that signal causes the *whole* view to be laid out again, including updating all the geometries (including headers, scroll bars, etc.). For simple models, that may not be an issue, but if the model has thousands of entries, that can take too much for something that shouldn't ask for that, for example when just changing the data of a single item (that may not even be visible).

Remember that item views use some level of optimization to avoid unnecessary computations, and that's also why there are very specific signals for different types of "changes" within the model: for instance, under normal circumstances, when `dataChanged()` is emitted for a single index, the view just repaints only the visual rectangle of that item, and only if it's currently visible in the viewport.

When using proxy models, that "about to" signal is **mandatory**.

### Using proper signals

When updating the data of an item, only `dataChanged()` should be emitted. For instance, `update_selected()` should theoretically become this:

```py
        for mindex in self.treeview.selectionModel().selectedRows():
            item = mindex.data(FamilyModel.Roles.ItemRole)
            item.name = random.choice(['A','B','C','D'])
            sourceIndex = self.proxyModel.mapToSource(mindex)
            self.itemModel.dataChanged.emit(sourceIndex, sourceIndex)
```

The above will tell the proxy that *just that index* has changed, and will eventually invalidate the model sorting/filtering; then, the proxy will sort/filter the items within its parent and will finally tell the view that the layout has actually changed (because it internally emits the layout change signals).

---

Then, what about item insertion (or removal)?

Well, when items are being added, the `beginInsertRows()` and `endInsertRows()` should *always* be used, just like you did for `add_family()`.

This brings us to another aspect: encapsulation.
While there's technically nothing wrong in calling model functions or signals from the outside world, it's always better to put the related functions within the object that actually access or modifies its contents. The above function should not change the data directly: instead, the model should expose a function that actually does that.

That's also why `setData()` should be implemented in custom models: not only because it's what views use to edit the model, but also because that function is a common interface that is also automatically accessed from proxy models. In such models, `setData()` directly calls the same function for the source model(s), automatically translating the index, so you don't need to explicitly convert it to the source: you can even ignore whether the view's model *is* a proxy or not.

```py
class FamilyModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    ...
    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role in (QtCore.Qt.EditRole, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
            item = index.internalPointer()
            item.name = random.choice(['A','B','C','D'])
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return True
        return False


class FamilyViewer(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    ...
    def update_selected(self):
        for mindex in self.treeview.selectionModel().selectedRows():
            self.treeview.model().setData(
                mindex, random.choice(['A','B','C','D']), QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
```

This is also valid for the `add_person()` function:

```py
class FamilyModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    ...
    def add_person(self, family, person):
        if not family in self.items:
            return
        familyIndex = self.index(self.items.index(family), 0)
        row = len(family.people)
        self.beginInsertRows(familyIndex, row, row)
        family.people.append(person)
        self.endInsertRows()


class FamilyViewer(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    ...
    def add_person(self):
        for mindex in self.treeview.selectionModel().selectedRows():
            item = mindex.data(FamilyModel.Roles.ItemRole)
            if isinstance(item, Family):
                self.itemModel.add_person(item, self.random_person())
```

### Final notes

There are other issues in your implementation.

First of all, remember that the `last` argument of `beginInsertRows()` (and `beginInsertColumns()`) is *not* the index after the addition. The following is wrong:

```py
    def append_families(self, items):
        first = self.rowCount()
        last = first + len(items)
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), first, last)
        self.items.extend(items)
        self.endInsertRows()
```

The *last index* is that of the last added item, not the index *after the last*. The logic is that you specify the indexes of the first and last items in the final entry list: if you want to insert an item at position 0, **both** `first` and `last` will be 0.
You're actually adding a further item, but the correct value of `last` is the following:

```py
        last = first + len(items) - 1
```

---

While the proposed implementation works fine, a more correct approach should use `createIndex()` with the *parent* as last argument of `createIndex()`.

The logic is that `createIndex()` works similarly to a basic `index()` call: the given pointer is the reference used to properly access the "child" item based on its row/column coordinates.

The common approach when implementing tree models is to create a basic class which is used as base for all items subclasses (including the root), so that child items (including top level items) can be easily accessed by common functions.

This approach may seem more convoluted, since it requires proper implementation of any access to QModelIndexes (including the pointers to the parents and reconstruction of the actual, final object), but it's also more appropriate and should correctly take care of object lifespan.

Some level of optimization would normally prefer "direct" pointer references, but that could result in inconsistent or unexpected behavior under certain circumstances. While performance is important, it should *never* override consistency and reliable usage.
Consider that this is also how QStandardItemModel works, since its `createIndex()` calls always use the parent item (see [`invisibleRootItem()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#invisibleRootItem)) as a pointer reference.